# Excel formula for working with multiples (factors)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, rounding, worksheet-function, factors

I need a formula on Excel which would deduct the multiple of 20 from a given number. For example:

2 would give you 18,
10 would give 10,
23 would give 17,
118 would give 2,
321 would give 19.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's worth noting that Excel has **built-in** functions for working with **multiples**: `CEILING` and `FLOOR` (in newer versions you have `CEILING.MATH` and `FLOOR.MATH`).

In your case, this should work:

```
=CEILING(A1,20)-A1
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to divide it by 20, round it up and multiply it by 20, the rest is trivial.

> =-(A1-ROUNDUP(A1/20,0)*20)

Comment: In this case feel free to accept my answer. I actually think you should accept ZygD's though.